# Using an IIFE and passing in parameters, when should I do it? Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, iife

Most sections of my library are made up of files that have a structure like so,

```
myLib.Something = (function() {

     function Something() {

     }

     return Something;

})();
```

Now suppose that inside `Something` I use `document` or `window` so now my file looks like this;

```
myLib.Something = (function() {

     function Something(id) {

         this.somethingElse = document.getElementById(id);
     }

     return Something;

})();
```

When using document inside `Something`'s constructor should I pass document into the IIFE, so that it would look like below;

```
myLib.Something = (function(document) {

     function Something(id) {

         this.somethingElse = document.getElementById(id);
     }

     return Something;

})(document);
```

Or should I only pass in variables to the IIFE when they are used outside of `Something`? Like below,

```
myLib.Something = (function(document) {

     var document = document;

     function Something() {

     }

     return Something;

})(document);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking for, but that `var document = document;` is absolutely useless there.

Comment: Should I pass in `document` or not when it is used inside `Something`'s constructor?

Comment: What you're trying to do is, protecting your `document`'s reference against being modified from the outside, like overwriting it `document = myCustomDocument`. So as long as the code, used, gets executed before usercode, pass it, afterwards the modifcations, made, would be reflected in your `document` either way.

Comment: You should not, for simplicity. Unless you definitely know that you need it - then you have an actual reason.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, your third and fourth examples are near-equivalent. Adding the `var document = document;` does nothing (and will throw errors in strict mode).

There are a couple of reasons you might use an IIFE here, although I don't think it's a necessity in this case.

Firstly, as @C5H8NNaO4 mentions, this can be used to make sure you have clean references to global objects. However this relies on your script being loaded before any user scripts.

Secondly, this will provide a cue to some minifiers that they can safely rename the variable inside your function. This can *sometimes* shave off a few extra bytes but it really depends on what tool you're using to minify code.

Lastly, the reason I might do this is that it *can* help with the readability of your code. This point could be debated, but I tend to pass arguments into my IIFE when I need to use them more than once and they reside in a deep namespace. For example:

```
(function (alias) {

    // do something with alias

} (library.that.has.namespaced.stuff));
```

Comment: `var document = document;` will not throw errors in strict mode; it will simply result in having a local `document` variable with the value `undefined`.